# How to compare 2 datagridview columns for duplicates vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, compare

I am having difficulty figuring this out. I have 2 DataGridViews and I need to compare 1 column from each and highlight duplicates. I am populating the DataGrids from an SQL database. The code I have so far is below. All this does is highlight every row. I am unsure how to get it to look through the column and find any duplicate values not just in the same row number.

```
        Dim RowOut As Integer
    Dim RowIn As Integer
    For Each rowOuter As DataGridViewRow In listOrderGrid.Rows
        For Each rowInner As DataGridViewRow In listWebPollingGrid.Rows
            RowOut = rowOuter.Cells("OrderID").Value
            RowIn = rowInner.Cells("OrderID").Value
            If rowInner.Cells("OrderID").Value = rowOuter.Cells("OrderID").Value Then
                rowOuter.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                rowInner.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            End If
            If rowOuter.Cells("OrderTypeName").Value = "Paid Out" Then
                rowOuter.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Violet
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: It would be faster and easier to compare the data from the datasource especially if you are looking for duplicate values independent of the ID.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I am new to working with databases in VB.net. I am pretty much self taught and I am unsure how to compare the data from the datasource. I am working on Googling it though.

Comment: Plutonix is right, it's much easier to take the data from the source and do the comparison. Instead of binding the results from your database to your DataGridView, assign it to a variable and scan that for duplicates. DataGridViews are used for displaying data rather than processing it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into that.